# Bandwidth needed to serve video

Tags: flash, performance, video, bandwidth

We are planning on serving some video on our website. In order to do so we are doing some contingency planning around the bandwidth we will use up during peak times.

We are planning on serving a 1 minute video at 150Kbs (we may increase this depending on how much bandwidth we use up). We are steaming the video, rather than embedding it.

In terms of users, we have calculated we should have about 3 users viewing video in any given **second**. We worked this out from visits to the site over an hour period, so within that hour we can expect this to peak at certain periods.

One [formula](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/calculating_bandwidth_02.html) we looked at was for Flash Media Server (which we are not using) but this formula the user for working out bandwidth probably still applies. We are interested if there is any other way to calculate the bandwidth required, and other 'gotchas' that people may have experienced.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At any one time - a 5Mb + connection should do you fine, any reasonable host should be able to provide you with this. If you are using shared hosting, you will probably get complaints with this sort of sustained bandwidth.

Also, sorry, I know this is not exactly helpful, but when I was looking at this a while ago for a client, we ended up just using YouTube and it was so much simpler and then others on YouTube can also view it - pulling more people to your site.

Comment: I'm interested in how you came to the 5Mb figure. YouTube is not an option for us.

Comment: The reason I said 5Mb is simply because @ 150Kbs, and 3 people watching would mean the equivalent of 450Kbs. So 5Mb/s should be more than enough and a good figure that many (good) hosts should be able to provide. Also, it is possible that unless you do auto start, many people will not watch or it will cache - or even people will skip to certain parts so you really want a good speed so it can load quick. If 3 people are watching the video, and, lets say it is around 9MB for the file, having a 5Mb pipe would be ample.

Comment: Sorry, forgot formatting gets lost. I hope you get the point. You could easily survive with a 1Mb connection, but I gave you a figure that will allow ample for now and allow you to grow in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer a calculation for how much bandwidth but would add the ["Digg Effect"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digg_effect) to one of the risks that you could get if it went viral